# New account has generic name and associations

Tags: support, linked-accounts, askubuntu

*Note*: the solution is to disassociate accounts and reassociate. Then copy your profile to fix the names. 
**Original**
I'm pretty confused about account associations. I went over the AskUbuntu site. I logged in with the same OpenID I've always used (from myopenid.com) and logged in as dlamblin; it found my accounts on SO, Meta, SF, SU etc. and showed my correct name and gravatar. I continued on and asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12307/how-do-i-re-activate-wake-the-monitors-from-the-command-line), and found that I had become [user5837](https://askubuntu.com/users/5837/user5837); when I tried to associate with the aforementioned accounts, it told me they were already associated with someone else.

This is basically feeling totally broken.

I would like the account and its question repaired... or be told how to repair it myself.

**Update**
In response to Micheal's comment, here's what it looks like to me (from the meta user's account page) and you can see it's happened before. And I've brought it up before. The same thing happens vice-versa on the User5837's account page trying to associate with any other account with the correct gravatar. 
[image: Already associated]

Comment: What do you see in [your accounts page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/459?tab=accounts)? I see several associated accounts and several more that offer to let me associate them (including Ask Ubuntu).

Comment: @Michael Myers yeah, I described it not working, now I'll show what I mean.

Comment: Ok, then I would suggest fully disassociating your On Startups, Apple, Ubuntu, and Stack Apps accounts. Then it should allow you to associate them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has to do with the old way of managing accounts, which has long been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you have multiple and possibly duplicate accounts on one or more sites.

1. Click "Clear All Associations"
2. Click "Associate with.." for each site.

Done.

Comment: Thanks; I didn't see that button before and it works